# Issue with Websphere Application Server in debug mode

Tags: java, debugging, websphere-7

I have problem while starting my WebSphere Application Server 7.0 in debug mode.I keep getting a window prompting for "Edit source Lookup Path".I have cleared wstemp,temp and after that the server got started in debug mode but the breakpoints are getting skipped.I couldn't find any difference whether the server runs in normal / debug mode.

IDE Used : Rational Application Developer 7.5.3

Please suggest a solution to run my WAS in debug mode and check with breakpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try updating your version of RAD to 7.5.5.5 (there might even be a newer version), and update your version of WAS to the latest patch as well. We had a lot of issues with earlier versions of RAD

Comment: It's not my personal PC, so couldn't make a update here.There are approvals to be taken for it.Kindly suggest fix by making any setting change by using existing version.Thanks.

Comment: If there's bugs in the app, there's not a whole lot you can do.

Comment: I have same setup in another PC where I can debug the code with breakpoints.Thats replica of the App which I have here.

Comment: Then I'd recommend a reinstall (and still recommend an update)

Comment: Thanks Goibniu. I have reimported a fresh workspace and have started the server after clearing translogs and temp , it's working fine now.